# How do I compile in C, but throw errors if I use any C++?

Tags: c++

I am a student. I am proficient with C++. I know that C++ and C are very similar and that a C++ compiler can compile C. However I want to become comfortable with C for a multitude of reasons. I was wondering if there is an option I can include with g++/gcc that will throw a error if I use C++. 
Thank you

Comment: Why not just use a C compiler?

Comment: gcc should give you an error for any c++ code if you use a .c file.

Comment: All versions of gcc/g++ support a set of standard and also gcc-specific preprocessor macros that can be used to detect whether compiling is as C or C++.   Check one or more of those macros and then use an `#error` directive to abort.    You could also include some code that is valid C and not valid C++ (and also not supported by gcc/g++ as an extension).   No way to force the compiler to abort on the command line, short of defining such a macro.

Answer (score 3):

To compile with the c use the -ansi synonymous with the -std=c89 flag.

```
gcc -ansi
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put in, say, major includes in your code something like

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#error "This is C code, please use C compiler"
#endif
```

and C++ compiler will throw error on preprocessor stage